# SQL - How to change a varchar column into date type in format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server table with some data imported from a `.csv` file. One of the columns `RegDate` is of type `varchar` and contains a date in format `ddmmyyyy`.

I need to convert the column to `date` datatype and in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. So the value `17112011` should be converted to `2011-11-17`.

Thanks:)

Comment: The `date` data type doesn't **have** a format. Internally, it's just a count of the number of days since 01/01/0001.

Comment: So you want it to add a year too? 1711***2011*** becomes ***2012***-11-17? :P  Why not on import cast it to date to begin with? or add a new column of date format populate it and then drop the original column?

Comment: I consider that this would by a typo, but in fact, it is possible to do that :)

Comment: How are you importing the data from CSV file to SQL Server table?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The typo was well spotted, edited now :) I am importing the data from csv with the import function in sql manager studio

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function in T-SQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, RegDate, 103) FROM myTable
```

Converts the VARCHAR field in your table to a DateTime type.

An option could be to add an extra column to your table which is of type DateTime.
Import the data from the CSV as is, and update the data afterwards:

```
UPDATE myTable SET ExtraDateTimeColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME, RegDate, 103)
```

I would consider this approach if this is a one-time import.

The format on how you want your DateTime to be represented, is just a representation form which you should handle in your UI/View logic imho

Comment: ... and then cast/convert it to `date` type because that is what the question asked for

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying both methods, i am getting this message in sql server management studio:

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Probably your csv contains a regdate which is not in the specific format or is no valid date.

Comment: Frederik Gheysels is right, your imported data probably contains incorrect date values (for example `29022017`). You can use ISDATE to check for any incorrect date values in your imported data, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `SUBSTRING` to re-arrange the import string value to a valid date format, which you can then `CAST` to datetime. So something like this:

```
SELECT
    RegDate, -- the import value

    SubString(RegDate, 5, 4) + '-' +  -- year
    SubString(RegDate, 3, 2) + '-' +  -- month
    SubString(RegDate, 1, 2) -- day
    as RegDate_str, -- the import value as YYYY-MM-DD

    CAST (
        SubString(RegDate, 5, 4) + '-' +  -- year
        SubString(RegDate, 3, 2) + '-' +  -- month
        SubString(RegDate, 1, 2) -- day
        as DateTime
    ) as RegDate_dt -- the import value cast as DateTime
FROM 
    MyImportTable
```

I don't know which datetime column you want to update based on values in `RegDate`. But you could add a new datetime column to your import table, and then update that new column like so:

```
UPDATE
    MyImportTable
SET
    MyDateTimeColumn =
    CAST (
        SubString(RegDate, 5, 4) + '-' +  -- year
        SubString(RegDate, 3, 2) + '-' +  -- month
        SubString(RegDate, 1, 2) -- day
        as DateTime
    )
WHERE
    len(RegDate) = 8 -- optionally, check length to make sure value is ok
```

Also, to quickly lookup any incorrect datevalues in your import table, you can use `ISDATE` to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    RegDate
FROM 
    MyImportTable
WHERE ISDATE(
        SubString(RegDate, 5, 4) + '-' +  -- year
        SubString(RegDate, 3, 2) + '-' +  -- month
        SubString(RegDate, 1, 2) -- day
    ) = 0 -- 0=invalid date, 1=valid date
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Can i execute an update statement in the same manner, in order to change the column value to Regdate_dt?

Comment: If you want to update the column `RegDate` that's possible but tricky. Because if you make a mistake with `UPDATE` then you have overwritten all the old `RegDate` values and you would have to run the import again. I think it's best to add a new column. If that went ok you can drop the old column and rename the new one. I've edited my answer with an update example.